# Retrieve all articles of people that have a biblio in Wikipedia or Mediawiki - using Wikipedia API or otherwise

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I’d like to gather all articles of people with a biblio section. My strategy is to retrieve all articles of people first by retrieving all articles in the category People and its descendants, then check if they have the section name “Bibliography”, “Works Cited” etc. For the former, I can use http://petscan.wmflabs.org. I am not sure how can I do the latter though.

Am I able to do this with the Wikipedia API? Either by (1) checking whether an article X has a section name Y (I will then feed the words “Bibliography”, “Works Cited” etc. into Y). (2) checking whether an article X has works cited natively (3) retrieving all articles that have works cited

I also welcome any other suggestions that will fulfil my aim, other than using the Wikipedia API.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [mobile sections API](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#/Mobile/getSections). Although you could just fetch the article from the web and look for headers with some DOM crawler, that's not much more difficult either.